# How do I remove the last characters of a string if they are equal to something?

Tags: php

How can I trim the last three characters when they are equal to `"01x"`?

**For example, I have this:**

```
$stuff = array(
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa1",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01x"
    "aaaaa11"
);
```

**I am trying to output:**

```
$stuff = array(
    "aaaaa", // trimmed
    "aaaaa1",
    "aaaaa", // trimmed
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa", // trimmed
    "aaaaa11"
);
```

I had problems trying to do this using `trim()`, because `trim()` trims off any string ending with any one of the three characters.

For example, `trim($string, '01x');` will trim off `"1"`, `"0"`, `"x"` from any string ending in those characters. I only want to trim when the string ends in "01x".

Comment: Test to see if the last three characters are '01x' and substring() if they are

Comment: `preg_replace('/01x$/', '', $string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stuff = array(
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa1",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa11"
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($stuff); $i ++)
{
    $stuff[$i] = (substr($stuff[$i], -3) == '01x' ? substr($stuff[$i], 0, -3) : $stuff[$i]);    
}
```

Comment: You do realize that your answer will throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"aaaaa11"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'`

Answer (score 1):

### Code:

```
$stuff = array(
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa1",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa11"
);

foreach($stuff as $key => $thing) {
   if(substr($thing, -3, 3) == '01x')
      $stuff[$key] = trim($thing, '01x');
}

var_dump($stuff);
```

### Output:

```
array(7) {
   [0]=> string(5) "aaaaa"
   [1]=> string(6) "aaaaa1"
   [2]=> string(5) "aaaaa"
   [3]=> string(7) "aaaaa01"
   [4]=> string(7) "aaaaa01"
   [5]=> string(5) "aaaaa"
   [6]=> string(7) "aaaaa11"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the array through a loop, and create a new array.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($stuff as $s){
$stuff[$i] = preg_replace('/01x$/', '', $s);
$i++;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to create a new array. just redefine the current one.

Comment: How do you redefine the current?

Comment: `$stuff[$i] = preg_replace('/01x$/', '', $stuff[$i] );` -- sorry. updated for your syntax... bah. I'm losing my mind...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the last position of the searchstring.

```
$stuff = array(
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa1",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01",
    "aaaaa01x",
    "aaaaa11"
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($stuff); $i++) {
    if (($pos = strrpos($stuff[$i], '01x')) !== FALSE) {
        $stuff[$i] = substr($stuff[$i], 0, $pos);
    }
}

print_r($stuff);
```